# Problem starting openni in ros electric

Tags: kinect, openni, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,   I recently downloaded ros/electric.
I was trying to run openni node with command :  roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch.
The result of this run is not stable. I get it to run at times and at other times, it just doesn't run.
It hangs and neither the topic /camera/depth_registered/points shows up anything with rostopic hz nor does rviz show anything.
Also, there is always an error I can see
[ERROR] [1314138567.670856122]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed/set_parameters]
[ERROR] [1314138567.677972703]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/theora/set_parameters]

I have no clue why this error exists. It exists even when the node hangs and doesn't publish anything .  I am using kinect.
Any Help appreciated.
~Cheers!
Neeraj

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10990/problem-starting-openni-in-ros-electric/) by [navderm](https://answers.ros.org/users/984/navderm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2011-08-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ANSWER UPDATED 9-2-11:

The Electric debs have recently been updated (between RC1 and final release) to include the Diamondback-style interface. I recommend that you try "roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch" rather than the new openni_launch package.

If you want to use openni_launch, you probably have to use dynamic reconfigure to turn on depth_registration, as it no longer does so automatically (you can also set a rosparam parameter). Some of the errors you saw with the openni_launch package is probably related to not having a calibration file, and can be safely ignored. If there are errors besides calibration, please post the full and exact error message.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jake](https://answers.ros.org/users/721/jake/) on 2011-08-26**:
I have the same problem.  Some times the depth points publish and sometimes they do not.  Below is a list of the errors that show during startup.   [ERROR] [1314382137.050990454]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed/set_parameters]
[ERROR] [1314382137.057244743]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/theora/set_parameters]